# Center elements in a grid row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, center

i have the following:

"

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><span class="label label-default">Current Job</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-10">
              <h6 id="dateTime">23/07/2015 12.00</h6>
            </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

</div>
<div class="panel-footer"></div>
```

"

Using only bootstrap, is it possible to center the two vertical labels of different dimensions (Current Job and Date) contained in Header panel (that contains a grid) and how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: very sorry. That link was working....
The new one is http://www.bootply.com/TLaZREN3rA

Comment: You misunderstand. The code should be **in the question** as well, not *just* in a link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the CSS for the following containers:

`<div class="col-md-3">` and `<div class="col-md-offset-10">`

Giving both containers `float: none;` and `margin: 0 auto` will definitely center both. If you want the text to be centered as well, add some `text-align: center`

That should have you covered.

Sorry, forgot to mention that the container `<div class="col-md-offset-10">` needs to match the width of the other container (25%).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thinks I wan't clear in my question.
     
In fact, I would like to leave the two labels in the same row but I'm trying to align them vertically inside their own cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing classes from your div tags for labels and giving text-center class to div with class row. This will make both labels appear in the middle of the page and one after another vertically. this is what your code container will look like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div>
      <h3><span class="label label-default">Current Job</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6 id="dateTime">22/07/2015 12:00:00</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thinks I wan't clear in my question.

Comment: In fact, I would like to leave the two labels in the same row but I'm trying to align them vertically inside their own cell.